# Convert html table to dict w/ beautifulsoup or lxml?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to convert a few html tables to dicts but I cant get it working, data below.. the 'Running' column has different amounts of links per row.

I only care about the Title, Name, and Running columns.

My end goal is a list with multiple dictionaries. I have been banging my head on this for a while and cannot get anything to work

`[{Title:'Randomnamehere1',Name:'Bob Dylan1',Running:[href, href, href]}, {Title:'Randomnamehere2',Name:'Bob Dylan2',Running:[href, href, href]}, {Title:'Randomnamehere3',Name:'Bob Dylan3',Running:[href, href, href]}]`

```
    <div class="span12">
      <table id="tests" class="responsive table pdf-table drop-row tablesorter" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0;">
        <thead>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Group</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Running</th>
          <th>Instructor Actions</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="/reports/532809">Randomnamehere</a>
            </td>
            <td>
              Bob Dylan (bd@letsgo.com)
            </td>
            <td>
              Group1
            </td>
            <td>
              01:54:20
            </td>
            <td>
              <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                PWS(s)
                  <li>
                  <a href="/user_section_items/532809/" target="_blank">local</a>
                  </li>
                  Mod_X010_C008
                    <li>
                    <a href="/user_section_items/532809/" target="_blank">lab:SC</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="/user_section_items/532809/" target="_blank">NIX</a>
                    </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
```

This is what I've gotten so far...

```
from lxml import html, etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

source = html.parse('source.html')
table = [c.text for c in source.xpath('//div[@class="span12"]//tbody//td/*//*')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop the table rows ignoring the header row and generate each dictionary within the loop. Append those to a global list to get your desired result. You can differentiate columns with `:nth-of-type`. In the case of the first column, you can just use `select_one` to match first `td`; a list comprehension can be used to extract the `href` attributes for your final output column.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''your html'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
results = []

for row in soup.select('#tests tr')[1:]:
    results.append(
    {
     'Title': row.select_one('td').text,
     'Name': row.select_one('td:nth-of-type(2)').text,
     'Running':[i['href'] for i in row.select('td:nth-of-type(5) a')]
    })

print(results)
```

Comment: This worked amazingly well, do you know how I could also grab the text from the page corresponding to each link? The NIX in this case                  <a href="/user_section_items/532809/" target="_blank">NIX</a>

Comment: `'text':[i.text for i in row.select('td:nth-of-type(5) a')]` ? where are you pulling it from?

Comment: Its the link text seen on the page, that you would click. Now I'm trying to make it so the href and link text are a dictionary inside the dictionary.